# Don't overflow container with grids and aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a scenario where I have to create a MxN grid dynamically keeping the grids square, the code for that situation is here

```js
rerender = (event) => {
  const height = document.getElementById("y-input").value;
  const width = document.getElementById("x-input").value;
  // console.log(`${event.target.id} :: ${event.target.value}`);
  console.log(`${height} :: ${width}`);

  const cellContainer = document.getElementById("cell-container");

  cellContainer.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${height}, 1fr)`;
  cellContainer.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${width}, 1fr)`;

  cellContainer.innerHTML = "";
  [...Array(height * width).keys()]
    .map(() => document.createElement('div'))
    .map((e) => {
      e.className = "cell";
      return e
    })
    .map((e) => cellContainer.appendChild(e))
}
```

```css
#grid-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: aqua;
  padding: 8px;
}

#cell-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.cell {
  background-color: blue;
  min-width: 4px;
  min-height: 4px;
  margin: 1px;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="x-input">width</label>
  <input value=2 min=1 max=50 type="number" name="x" id="x-input" style="width: 4ch;" onchange="rerender(event)">
  <label for="y-input">height</label>
  <input value=2 min=1 max=50 type="number" name="y" id="y-input" style="width: 4ch;" onchange="rerender(event)">
</div>

<div id="grid-container">
  <div id="cell-container">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using the grid layout where number of rows and columns are being changed dynamically by this

```
cellContainer.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${height}, 1fr)`;
cellContainer.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${width}, 1fr)`;
```

and using the `aspect-ratio` property to keep the cells square. The code works perfectly when we are drawing the square(height and width are same) and in a rectangular case where width is greater than height.

The rectangular case where height is greater than width is also working but in that case there is y-overflow, how can I prevent that overflow ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-violet-kk6h9

[image]

Comment: can you send a screenshot of the overflow?

Comment: so your total height of boxes altogether are higher than your parent container correct? you want to make it scrollable or hide all the content overflowing? please provide more info of what you wanna do with overlapped content.

Comment: the cells inside them don't have a fixed size(both height and width), although they have min-height and min-width and 1:1 aspect ratio, if you check the case where width is grater than hight you will find that there is some empty area inside the container, below the cell, I need that empty area in the right side of the cells having no y-overflow and smaller cell size.

Comment: Do you want the outer container (aqua) to fill or scroll if there is overflow as shown in the screenshot ?

Comment: fill not scroll, it's ok that cell sizes get reduced which is happening in the case of width greater than height

Comment: @JayendraParmar don't hesitate to ask if there is anything I'm missing in my answer before the bounty runs out ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## TL;DR

Since everything is a square, we can use fake rows and columns to size the cells properly. Solution at the end of this post.

## Explanation

### Problem definition

If I understand your problem correctly, you want

- a `W`×`H` cells grid
- that fits inside a `N`×`N` pixels square
- where each cell is a square

### Starting point, what already works

So in the case that you got working, say for example, `W=3; H=2`, we get a result that looks like this:

[image: 3×2 cells]

### Refactoring for pure CSS

I assume that we're looking for a pure-CSS solution, since a JS solution would be both trivial and suboptimal. So before we proceed, let's modify the JS to just give us [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) and then we can reason in CSS only:

- we're defining `--per-row`, the number of cells in 1 row,
- we're defining `--per-col`, the number of cells in 1 column.

```js
grid.style.setProperty('--per-row', width);
grid.style.setProperty('--per-col', height);
```

```
#grid {
  --per-row: 2;
  --per-col: 2;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--per-row), 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--per-col), 1fr);
}
```

*PS: in every code snippet, I'll omit the lines that aren't relevant to the current discussion.*

### Understanding the issue

Now what doesn't work in your solution is when `H > W`, so let's take an example where `W=2; H=3`. We want our grid to look like this:

[image: 2×3 cells]

But since the parent (cyan blue box) is also a square, we can see that this example and the previous one have the same resulting cell dimensions. In the case of `W=3; H=2` we kind of see an empty line at the bottom; and in the case of `W=2; H=3` we kind of see an empty column on the right. **In both cases, we lay out our cells in a `3×3` grid!** This is simply `max(width, height)`:

[image: 3×3 grid]

So let's create this grid with [CSS max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max()):

```css
#grid {
  --per-row: 2;
  --per-col: 2;
  --max: max(var(--per-row), var(--per-col));
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--max), 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--max), 1fr);
}
```

However, with this grid template, we'll always create 3 columns in both the `3×2` case and the `2×3` case. It's going to work great for `W > H` but the `H > W` will look wrong. We need to refactor how the columns template is calculated.

1. First, the number of column we actually want. That's the easy part, it's `--per-row`:

   ```css
   grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--per-row), 1fr);
   ```

   But now our `2×3` grid looks like this because each column is `1fr`, which results in `50%` of the full width:

   [image: 2×3 cells, with columns that are too large]
2. Now, we need to find the proper width of a column. We've seen that using `1fr` doesn't work, but since everything is a square, we know that in both the `3×2` case and the `2×3` case we need each column to be ⅓ of the width, or `100% / 3`, or `calc(100% / var(--max))`:

   ```css
   grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--per-row), calc(100% / var(--max)));
   ```

### **tadaa!**

We now have a layout that will work for any `W` and `H` with two simple lines of CSS:

```css
#grid {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--per-row), calc(100% / var(--max)));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--max), 1fr);
}
```

### Cleaning up

1. Because of how "vertical" layout works (technically, "block direction" in [CSS flow layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flow_Layout)), we can simplify how rows are created. `grid-template-rows` will create a fixed number of rows, but now that we have a strong definition for the number of columns in `grid-template-columns`, we can just say "create as many rows as needed to fit all of the children", which is exactly what [grid-auto-rows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-rows) does:

   ```css
   grid-auto-rows: calc(100% / var(--max));
   ```

   This uses the same math as for the width of the columns, since everything here is a square.
2. Because support for CSS `max()` still isn't great, this is something we can do in JS without any performance issue:

   ```js
   grid.style.setProperty('--per-row', width);
   grid.style.setProperty('--per-col', height);
   grid.style.setProperty('--max', Math.max(width, height));
   ```
3. You'll notice that at this point, we aren't using `--per-col` anymore thanks to `grid-auto-rows`, so we can remove it:

   ```js
   grid.style.setProperty('--per-row', width);
   grid.style.setProperty('--max', Math.max(width, height));
   ```

   ```css
   #grid {
     --per-row: 2;
     --max: 2;
   }
   ```

## Solution

Here's your initial code, with the modifications explained in my answer.

```js
rerender = (event) => {
  const height = document.getElementById("y-input").value;
  const width = document.getElementById("x-input").value;
  const grid = document.getElementById("grid");

  grid.style.setProperty('--per-row', width);
  grid.style.setProperty('--max', Math.max(width, height));

  grid.innerHTML = "";
  [...Array(height * width).keys()]
    .forEach(() => {
      const e = document.createElement('div')
      e.className = "cell";
      grid.appendChild(e)
    })
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: aqua;
  padding: 8px;
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  --per-row: 2;
  --max: 2;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--per-row), calc(100% / var(--max)));
  grid-auto-rows: calc(100% / var(--max));
  gap: 2px;
}

.cell {
  background-color: blue;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="x-input">width</label>
  <input value=2 min=1 max=50 type="number" name="x" id="x-input" style="width: 4ch;" onchange="rerender(event)">
  <label for="y-input">height</label>
  <input value=2 min=1 max=50 type="number" name="y" id="y-input" style="width: 4ch;" onchange="rerender(event)">
</div>

<div id="container">
  <div id="grid">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for this awesome solution, with detailed explanation, a one missing bit in this is that the calculation is accounting the gap, I think can fix that.

Comment: @JayendraParmar yep technically my solution breaks the more cells you add because of spacings, but that's easily solvable ;-) I prefer focusing on the "tricky" part of the issue.

Comment: yes that was nevertheless helpful thanks.

Comment: @JayendraParmar would you mind accepting this post as the answer if you feel it did answer your question? And otherwise tell me what it's missing.